# define-fun vs define-funs-rec in smtlib

Tags: z3, smt, cvc4

It seems that `define-funs-rec` is a strict superset of what `define-fun` can do according to the [SMTLIB standard](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2017-07-18.pdf). If so is there a reason for not always using `define-funs-rec`, maybe except for syntactic simplicity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking; no. But `define-fun-rec` is rather new (as opposed to good old `define-fun`), so if you want greater portability and have no need for a recursive definition, then you should stick to `define-fun`.

It is conceivable that the `define-fun-rec` might also bring heavier-machinery in a solver that is not really needed unless you really have a recursive definition, such as a well-foundedness checker. This might end up costing some performance cycles; though I doubt this would be too much of a concern.

Comment: A decent mental model for `define-fun` is "the solver will apply eager beta reduction", and `define-fun-rec` is roughly "the solver will introduce universal quantifiers + an uninterpreted functions". This is not necessarily true of the implementation, but it should get you a decent ways.